# how to set tokenid in erc721 openzeppelin?

Tags: erc-721, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

First of all, sorry if I'm asking an obvious question.

In ERC721 openzeppelin API, to manage a token you always need to refer to a tokenId.

Are you supposed to define a global variable, or a mapping in the case of enumerable, in the contract to refer to tokenId? Is this the best way to go, or should you use any method to set tokenId?

Comment: Please share the relevant code.

Comment: when the token is generated it will get its token id:
 _mint(address to, uint256 tokenId)
And the token id will be added to owner in this variable:    
mapping (address => EnumerableSet.UintSet) private _holderTokens;

Answer (score 2):

A tokenId in [EIP 721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) is an unique arbitrary number you assign to each one of your tokens.

From the specification:

> While some ERC-721 smart contracts may find it convenient to start with ID 0 and simply increment by one for each new NFT, callers SHALL NOT assume that ID numbers have any specific pattern to them, and MUST treat the ID as a “black box”.

You can assign consecutive numbers starting from 0, or a more complex formula. If the numbers do not repeat you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to be sure if there was a convention about that, or not.